# Wherever I May Roam 2000

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay, english

> `(01)` I never give a single hair to the carder
> `(02)` shrunken by boob, I try even harder
> `(03)` drupy and pitted and jammed in the larder
> `(04)` but when throwing or dancing I'm jumping with ardor
>
> `(05)` some call me small, but they don't know jack
> `(06)` while one of my brothers plays chess, white and black
> `(07)` some say that I gleam from a chicken shack
> `(08)` and some think that I fear some straw on a rack
>
> `(09)` at 14 I'll shine in regal resplendence
> `(10)` as Sam I enjoy ornithovorous attendance
> `(11)` add 4 and I'm many in interdependence
> `(12)` but careful, because I bring death, in abundance
>
> `(13)` you can call me Suzanne, do you like what I play?
> `(14)` for the king of games think of Hulk I portray
> `(15)` I help you walk with your nerves gone astray
> `(16)` but you get on your hands and mock how I stay
>
> `(17)` I'm undead in caps, but get played by a dead
> `(18)` I stream ruby ponies with a rather short head
> `(19)` bordering Spain I'm a trustworthy lad
> `(20)` but serve me a drink and I burgle instead

Bonus line:

> Before the time on Amaret, where it is me you hear,
> South forty were not dead, but that they were not here.

---

Clarification about lines 1 and 14:

> Line 1 is just a general hint for warm-up, not a play on the word.
>  Soon after posting I realized that line 14 would mislead. I reworded, so I hope it's less misleading now. - To clarify: line 14 does not have a green banner, it is red and dread.

EDIT: *I switched lines 1 and 2 compared to the original posting. Sorry for the confusion, but I think it just works better that way.*

Comment: I dont get it, are we supposed to answer each line? Or all the lines are one answer?

Comment: @Gustavo - Each phrase is a different hint at the same answer. If several lines are meant to be understood as a phrase, it should be obvious enough from the way it's worded. So there is one answer, but your ideas about what the individual phrases mean are part of the fun. - So far, my riddles got solved too quickly for my taste. So this time I wanted to wait a bit, before I add hints. Still figuring out the balance.

Comment: +1 for the amazing rhyme in lines 9 and 10 :D

Comment: Let me know if you are still at it. If you are done with it, I'll post the rest of the answers

Comment: OK, seems like nobody is puzzling on this any longer, so I'll now fill in the missing details in the solution posting.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Partial answer...

> A lot of these things are connected to a **crow** (or a raven).

*some think that I fear some straw on a rack*

> That would be a scarecrow.

*I bring death, in abundance*

> A pack of crows is called a murder.

*Before the time on Amaret, where it is me you hear, South forty were not dead, but that they were not here.*

> The rock band [Crow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crow_(band))'s label was Amaret Records. They were originally called *South 40*.

*I'm undead in caps, but get played by a dead*

> [The Crow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Crow) is an undead superhero. He was played by Brandon Lee, who died during filming.

*I gleam from the chicken shack\serve me a drink and I burgle instead*

> Crows have been known to steal shiny objects as well as eggs from chicken coops (I'm assuming the play on glean\gleam is intentional). **Edit:** And crow+bar=crowbar, which is used by burglars. ***[Thanks, M Oehm!]***

*you can call me Suzanne, do you like what I play?*

> Possibly alludes to musician [Sheryl *Suzanne* Crow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sheryl_Crow).

*drupy and pitted and jammed in the larder*

> There *are* [crowberries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empetrum_nigrum), which can be made into a jam. Their fruits are drupes, hence 'drupy'.

*while one of my brothers plays chess, white or black*

> This refers to a [rook](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rook_(bird)), which is also a member of the crow family (Corvidae) [***Thanks, M Oehm!***].

*shrunken by boob*

> Possibly alludes to a [crowtit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fulvous_parrotbill), a tiny bird [***Thanks, M Oehm!***].

*at 14 I'll shine in regal resplendence*

> Crow + the 14th letter (N) = Crown

*add 4 and I'm many in interdependence*

> Crow + the 4th letter (D) = Crowd

*I help you walk with your nerves gone astray*

> Perhaps a CROW boot (Charcot Restraint Orthotic Walker), for people with damaged nerves.

*Wherever I May Roam 2000*

> Well, Metallica performed this song in Baltimore in 2000, and Baltimore's football team is called the Ravens, named after the poem by Edgar Allan Poe  (who's buried in Baltimore).

Those are the ones I can think of so far... I'll try and add others later on.

Comment: Very good! The chess-playing relative is a rook; the es-crow ("bordering Spain") is trustworthy; a crow-bar is a burglar's tool; a crow-tit is a small tit-like bird.

Comment: @MOehm D'oh, I forgot rooks are related to crows... Nice one, and I'll try to figure out the rest, I promise. ;)

Comment: Great Job! You got it. - As for the details, you totally hit 3 ("drupy" because they are drupes), 8, 12, 13 and 17 so far. M Oehm added 6, 19 and 20. The Bonus you have almost complete, just add why they were not here. For the title: Cool! I had something totally different in mind. - for 9 (resplendence) I really like your take on that, but as with 7 (chicken shack) there is a more literal solution. - Very nice, thanks!

Comment: Ah, I think I've got the "regal" and "many" lines, but why 16? Shouldn't that be "At 14, ..."?

Comment: @KarstenKöpnick D'oh II, I confused you with M Oehm [corrected]. I'll get cracking on the rest.

Comment: @ M Oehm: Crap!!! - erm, I mean: 16, who said 16??? Cough, cough. Late at night, cough, confused with line numbers, wanted one that matched it's line, too dumb to count. Many much sorry. (Thanks for your correction)

Comment: @MOehm You're supplying a lot of good solutions, BTW! Do you prefer to post them in a separate answer (and I'll remove them from my own)?

Comment: @Walt: No, I'll just leave them here, if you don't mind, and you can use them if you want (no need to attribute). You have found the answer (well done!), but it's common for people here to fill in blanks in partial solutions. I'll stop now, so you can fill in the rest yourself

Comment: @Walt: Before you continue, please have a look at the hint I added.

Comment: @KarstenKöpnick [Line 2] Um. Because they don't have hair? ;) I mean, I added a few solutions, but I think I'm running on fumes here...

Comment: @Walt, Yep, that's it for 2. - All your new solutions match what I had in mind. I kept up with your edits and updated my official solution posting accordingly, didn't want to flood the comments..

Comment: 5 is likely jackdaw.

Answer (score 3):

**OP's solution to the riddle "Wherever I may roam 2000"**

*individual lines get posted one by one, as they get solved*

The overall answer (provided by Walt) is

> **Crow**

`(01)` I never give a single hair to the carder (by Walt)

> This is just a general hint that we are dealing with a bird here. Birds have feathers, so no hair for the carder.

`(02)` shrunken by boob, I try even harder (by M Oehm)

> The *crow tit* is small bird (so the tit shrinks the crow here). Supposedly, the term "crow tit" is somewhat synonymous for "try hard" due to a Korean saying.

`(03)` drupy and pitted and jammed in the larder (by Walt)

> *Crow berries* (which are drupes) can be cooked into jam. Jam typically requires pitting (removing the stones). And a larder is a typical storage place for the jars.

`(04)` but when throwing or dancing I'm jumping with ardor (not found)

> The *crow hop* is a step technique used for instance in Baseball for stronger/farther throws, and also occurs as a move in fancy or freestyle dance.

`(05)` some call me small, but they don't know jack (by hagfy)

> The *jackdaw* is the smallest type of corvus, the name literally meaning "small bird". If you know this Jack, than a common crow is not the small one.
>  Also it's a common misconception that crows are the smaller brethren of ravens, while actually both names are widely applied to a range of species (albeit mostly the "crow" being the smaller one than the "raven" of the region, as far as I know). If you know about the jackdaw, you probably know proper classification terminology and understand that calling crows small is simplified enough to being wrong.

`(06)` while one of my brothers plays chess, white and black (by M Oehm)

> The *Rook* is a small type of corvus, and also a playing piece in chess. "White and black" was meant to hint at the playing pieces themselves.

`(07)` some say that I gleam from a chicken shack (not found)

> (Yeah, I know I need to apologise, the meter here only works with the help of a sledgehammer)
>  *Cockcrow* is prosaic for "(at the) first light of day" (hence *gleam* and "cock" -> *chicken shack*). The word allegedly comes from the every-too-early-morning screaming fit of terror, allegedly precisely 5 minutes before even the sun itself knows it's rising, that so spit-beggingly inheres in roosters.

`(08)` and some think that I fear some straw on a rack (by Walt)

> A *scarecrow* is made of straw. And while it might work on some birds, it's notoriously useless in scaring away the very crows it's named after.

`(09)` at 14 I'll shine in regal resplendence (by M Oehm)

> *Crown*. 14 here refers to the 14th letter of the alphabet "n". "At 14" here means "crow" at "n" = crown.  A common item of royal pomp.

`(10)` as Sam I enjoy ornithovorous attendance (not found)

> This one is totally straight, I'm surprised no one found it - nah, just kidding: *Sam Crow* is a pseudo name for the Acronym SAMCRO, which stands for "Sons of Anarchy Motorcycle Club Redwood Original" of the TV series "Sons of Anarchy". Several women hang out with the club as groupies, for members of Sam Crow to enjoy what they politely call attendance, and they are called *crow eaters*.
>  So more precisely that term should have been *corvovorous*, but I didn't want to give it away too easily ;-)

`(11)` add 4 and I'm many in interdependence (by M Oehm)

> *Crowd*. The 4 to add is the 4th letter of the alphabet "d". Interdependence is what makes many a group.

`(12)` but careful, because I bring death, in abundance (by Walt)

> a flock of crows is called a *murder* (hence the comma. It's to mean *I in abundance*, not *bring death in abundance*)

`(13)` you can call me Suzanne, do you like what I play? (by Walt)

> Refers to the musician *Sheryl Suzanne Crow*

`(14)` for the king of games think of Hulk I portray (by hagfy)

> *Crow Hogan* (reminiscent in name of Hulk Hogan) is a figure in Yu-Gi-Oh, which literally means King of Games. (He does not appear in the original series, but in spin-offs, but they are still named Yu-Gi-Oh something.) - I only found out after posting that there is a The Hulk card in the Yu-Gi-Oh CCG. I reworded the line to be less misleading. Sorry, tried to double-check everything before posting.

`(15)` I help you walk with your nerves gone astray (by Walt)

> A *Charcot Restraint Orthotic Walker*, CROW for short, is an ankle/foot orthotic in form of a stable boot that helps with walking if the foot is sick with Charcot neuroarthropathy.

`(16)` but you get on your hands and mock how I stay (not found)

> To assume the yoga *crow pose* you stand on your hands in a crouching (or maybe crowching) position and look silly. (I'm no expert, the last part might be non-obligatory, but even in people far more elegant than I am, it looks like mockery at best).

`(17)` I'm undead in caps, but get played by a dead (by Walt)

> Refers to the movie *The Crow* (in caps meaning in capitals, hinting at it to be a title). The Crow character is an undead, a revenant, returned from the dead for vengeance.
>  Crow actor Brandon Lee tragically died during the filming of the movie. But with special effects, some scenes and thus the movie were completed even after his death.

`(18)` I stream ruby ponies with a rather short head (not found)

> The Shorthead Redhorse is the most common fish in the *crow river*.
>  (Yeah I admit, I was short for one line. This one is just a very tiny bit forced.)

`(19)` bordering Spain I'm a trustworthy lad (by M Oehm)

> *Escrow*. (Crow bordering ES, which stands for for Spain/Espana)

`(20)` but serve me a drink and I burgle instead (by M Oehm)

> *Crowbar*. A drink is served at a bar. A crowbar is not uncommonly implemented in the context of burglary.

The title "Wherever I may roam 2000" refers to (possibly superseded by Walt :-)

> The Britsh *Countryside and Rights of Way Act 2000*, or *CRoW Act* for short, which implements the "right to roam" to a broader area in November 2000.
>  *Walt had a very different answer, and a very cool one, so I should make it official:*
>  Metallica performed this song in Baltimore in 2000, and Baltimore's football team is called the Ravens, named after the poem by Edgar Allan Poe (who's buried in Baltimore).

And the bonus line: (basically solved by Walt)

> The first album released by the Minneapolis-based band *Crow*, still named *South 40* then, was called *Live at Someplace Else*.
>  When they recorded their first studio album "Crow Music", they already had changed their name to "Crow" and were contracted to *Amaret Records*.
>  The term bonus line was meant to ring like bonus track and hint on music albums.

Comment: (5) jackdaw and (14) Crow Hogan from Yu-Gi-Oh?